# Window width doesn't fit to device fit

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, window

I'm trying to make a Bootstrap 3 navbar and it should collapse at the 768px width size. But it doesn't work. I checked it why it's happening and I realized it sees window width as 980px whatever its size is.

My site is: http://dev.semcoled.com

I console.log'ged and alerted the window width, it always prompts 980px even if the device is smaller than it.

I don't know why does that happen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the problem:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```